# Continuous Function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Cannot Be One-One

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I stumbled upon a slightly more general question than the title, phrased as follows:

> Given a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and a function $f: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous in some deleted neighbourhood of $a$, prove that $f$ is not one-one when $k \geq 2$.

Intuitively, I can get a feel to how this theorem works. There are examples all around me that demonstrate this question. However, I am still pretty far from proving it...
I know that there is a greater "degree of freedom" for the inputs than the outputs if that makes any sense but I am quite confused as to how the whole continuity idea brings the whole question together. Any clues would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

### **Edit:**

I got a small (maybe a little bigger than "small") hint from my professor suggesting I should use the intermediate value theorem from Calculus Ⅰ. And that I should think of some curve in the said neighbourhood to help me out here, since I can only apply this theorem to single variable functions. So I started with the following idea:

Let
$$
N^* = \{\text{Deleted neighbourhood of } a \text{ in which } f \text{ is continuous}\}
$$

Given two simple curves:
$$
\quad \varphi_1,\varphi_2: [0,1] \rightarrow N^* \text{ s.t: } \\
\begin{align*}
\text{(*) }  & \qquad \varphi_1((0,1)) \cap \varphi_2((0,1)) = \varnothing \\
             & \qquad \varphi_1(0)=\varphi_2(0),\varphi_1(1)=\varphi_2(1)
\end{align*}
$$

let us establish that $\alpha = f \circ \varphi_1(0) = f \circ \varphi_2(0)$ and $\beta = f \circ \varphi_1(1) = f \circ \varphi_2(1)$.

Thus, we have $f \circ \varphi_1: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f \circ \varphi_2: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that are both continuous and equal at their boundary points.

Using the intermediary value theorem we can say that there exist $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 \in [0,1]$ s.t $f \circ \varphi_1(\gamma_1) = f \circ \varphi_2(\gamma_2)$

And by (*) we can safely assume $\varphi_1(\gamma_1) \neq \varphi_2(\gamma_2)$ which is what we wanted to prove.

My formalism isn't really on point but I can't spot any flaw in the logic as of right now.

Thank you so much!